# Pygame : event.type works only for one case

Tags: python, events, pygame, keyboard

I have a problem with my pygame code, which seems correct but doesn't work as it should.
I want to do different actions depending the key pressed; when I put two cases, only one works.
I put my code below :

```
        gamestate.draw(window)
        pygame.display.update()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT or (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.type == pygame.K_ESCAPE):
                finis = True
            if (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_UP):
                print("ok")
        pygame.display.update()
```

Here, my code print "ok" in the terminal when I press the UP key, but doesn't quit when I keep the escape key pressed.
It isn't this particular case that doesn't work, before it quit when i pressed escape and didn't print "ok" when i pressed the up key.
Do you have any idea to solve my issue ? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pygame.K_ESCAPE` is not an event type but you check for `event.type`:

```py
... and event.type == pygame.K_ESCAPE
```

It should be:

```py
... and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE
```

Also usually if you have to check for multiple keys on `pygame.KEYDOWN` event, then use nested `if`s:

```py
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
        finis = True
    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        print('ok')
```

Also you need to call `pygame.display.update` only ONCE in the loop (most likely at the end) NOT twice